# Discord.py Write direct message to user

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

How do I let my bot send a message to a user I only have the username from?
I wanna send notify a user when if he has got unbanned.

```
@client.command()
@commands.bot_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user
        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f"Unbanned {user.mention}")
            ### here i want to send the user a message that he was unbanned ###
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a member from his/her username, you can use `MemberConverter`, but in your case, you cannot do that. Because you cannot send DM to a user that doesn't share the same guild with the bot. That means you cannot send message to a user if he's not in the guild.

Comment: and if i save the member id of this person? before he gets banned

Comment: It doesn't matter. The bot must be in at least 1 common guild with the person you want to send message.